# Show and hide element through different tabs PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select inside a form with different types of devices from the database (`devices.insert.php`):

```
Type:<select name="type" form="form_select" onchange="showDiv(this)">
     <?php 
     $sql = "SELECT * 
     FROM Property
     WHERE PRP_PRP_TYP_Id = 1";
     $result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql);
     echo "<option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>";
     while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "<option value='".$row['PRP_Id']."'>".$row['PRP_Value']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
  </select><br>


<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(elem){
   if(elem.value == 3 || elem.value == 24 || elem.value == 25){
      document.getElementById('sc_div').style.display = "block";
   }
   else{
      document.getElementById('sc_div').style.display = "none";
   }

}
</script>
```

And when I select one of the items with the correct `id`, a `div` element turns visible with more options.

```
<div id="sc_div" style="display:none">
...
<a href="sim_cards_insert.php">Register new SIM</a><br>
</div>
```

In `sim_cards_insert.php` I have a form with submit and cancel and when I press to go back (to `devices_insert.php`) the div `sc_div` is not visible again but the data that I've filled before is in the same place.

```
<button type="button" class="log-btn" onClick="history.go(-1)">Cancel</button>
```

How can I get it visible again passing through different windows?

Comment: You can try to reset the element on page leave...
 onunload = function ()
    {
        document.getElementById("elementId").reset();
    };

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the browser is reverting the DOM to it's initial state - ie with the `sc_div` hidden.

Perhaps you could check the previous URL for the `devices_insert.php` page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(elem){
   //example
   var filename = document.referrer.split('/').pop();
   if(filename === 'sim_card_insert.php'){
        document.getElementById('sc_div').style.display = "block";
   }

   //...rest of function
</script>
```